# Autofac IEnumerable resolve cause multiple construction

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, resolve, generic-interface

I have this registration:

```
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IBusinessRule<>))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .SingleInstance();
```

And I resolve it this way:

```
 using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
 {
        var rules = Container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IBusinessRule<T>>>();

        var result = rules.Select(x => x.IsValid(t));

        if (result.Any(x => !x.Successful))
        {
            var msg = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.Where(x => !x.Successful).Select(x => x.Message));

            return new OperationResultBase()
            {
                Message = msg,
                Successful = false,
                Operation = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new OperationResultBase(true);
        }
  }
```

The problem lies in this line:

```
var result = rules.Select(x => x.IsValid(t));
```

With that resolve, the classes that implement the `IBusinessRule<T>` are called once per each `result` variable enumeration.

If I call `ToList()` on `result`, then everything is OK and would be called only once.

Is calling `ToList()` a correct approach or the registration has some problems and should be changed?

Answer (score 3):

> Is calling ToList() a correct approach or the registration has some problems and should be changed?

No, Nothing wrong with your registration. This is the lazy evaluation property of Linq.

In fact it has nothing to do with the autofac. A normal lazy linq query would exactly behave the same way as you see.

If you need the materialized result, you need to call `ToList` or `ToArray`. Otherwise, query will be evaluated on each enumeration (for example via foreach);

Comment: I know the **Lazy** evaluation is in effect but shouldn't the `Resolve` really does resolve instead of giving a reference for future REAL resolving?

Comment: @MohsenAfshin Resolve done only once. Repeated actions is a result of Linq behaviour. At var result = rules.Select(x => x.IsValid(t)); you have not any enumeration. Next you do result.Any which means you do rules.Select(x => x.IsValid(t)).Any() and then once more result.Where which means you do rules.Select(x => x.IsValid(t)).Where(...). To break this you have to add ToList() which will 'cache' your validation result. Then you will enumerate this 'cache'

Comment: @MohsenAfshin ATM I can't access the autofac documentation now. I believe this is documented somewhere. To be on the safer side, I always call `ToArray` myself to materialize the query.